# Automatically adjust margin of different data in of the single row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, vertical-alignment, margins

I am getting data , which first arranges itself into column by  `<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 border-right mb-4">` and than into row by `<div class ="row">`. Now what happens if data in different column in row 1  takes different space that is some take more space than other , now the data in second row will adjust its margin-bottom according to the data which has max space in row 1, in this case some column of row 1 has less data and have space , which is not occupied by row 2  data because it adjust itself according max data of col of row 1.

In the image above the line between two blocks  shows the space in second and third row is the problem. I want remove that space but its fixed due to position of the 1st column 1st row data.

[image]

The solution to this through css and bootstrap

```
<div class="dropdown-menu megamenu sm-menu border-top" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

        <div class="row" style= "padding:auto">
          @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 border-right mb-4">
            <h6>{{$subcategory->category_name}}</h6>
            @if(count($subcategory->subcategory))
                @include('layouts.subcategoryListlink',['subcategories' => $subcategory->subcategory])
            @endif
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your question is more or less difficult and easy to answer depending on even which version of Bootstrap you're using. Unfortunately nobody can see your code @Piyush. Take a look here ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the scenario and code please check and response

and the code for this is

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version and show rendered HTML, not PHP. This is not a PHP question.